# How to Access Locally Hosted Website using DNS

Tags: php, synology

I have a Synology NAS hosting my PHP website that uses a GoDaddy DNS.

Currently, if I want to access my website using the DNS over the internet I have to change the $_GLOBAL variable URLROOT I set to the DNS and if I want to access the site locally, I have to change the URLROOT to my Synology’s local IP.

Is there a way I can access the site both locally and over the internet while using the DNS?

A thought that crossed my mind is potentially changing the URLROOT depending on the user’s IP, but I’m not sure that’s possible.

Comment: Don't use `$_GLOBAL` at all. Put the IP into a environment variable and access via [getenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv).

Comment: Shouldn't your webserver configuration be handling DNS? If you're using Nginx, you can use `server_name _;` or specify any of the ones you use like `server_name myapp.local myapp.com;` If you're fronting it elsewhere, then use `proxy_pass`